# Add ASP tag dynamically in ASPX page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add ASP controls tag dynamically which are coming from database.

Here is the sample of my code.

```
private void BindDynamicFields()
{
    DataTable dtTemp = new DataTable();
    DataSet ds = clsContact_Field_Management.SelectAll();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.Append("<table cellpadding='3' cellspacing='1' border='0' width='100%' >");
    sb.Append("<tr>");
    sb.Append("<td align='left' width='18%' valign='top'>"+ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Field_Name"]+"</td>");
    sb.Append("<td align='center' width='4%' valign='top'>:</td>");
    sb.Append("<td align='left' width='28%' valign='top'>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Field_Value"] + "</td>");
    sb.Append("</tr>");
    sb.Append("</table>");

   tblEditContact.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
}
```

In this line of code `tblEditContact` is `DIV` tag in my `ASPX` page. In that `DIV` tag I want to add ASP `textbox` control dynamically.

`ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Field_Value"]` is coming from database and it's value is `<asp:TextBox ID='txtCompany' runat='server' Width='170px' MaxLength='50' />` but when I run this code I got this.

[image: asp control missing]

There is missing `asp:textbox` control after **:** mark.

Please help if possible.

Comment: It would be easier to use a GridView. And you cannot add a Control as a string value, that won't work. You can add the TextBox to the `TemplateField` or as Dynamic Controls.

Comment: first of all dont put client side code on server side , it will be difficult for you to modify in future, you can just pass the dataset to view